# Creating JPA model class for a table which does not have primary key defined but has unique index created

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Creating JPA model class for a table  which does not have primary key defined  but has unique index created .

For example there is a table popular_item table which has  columns like itemEntityId, itemType, itCode,quantity, status,createdDate.
Among these if the columns itemEntityId, itemType, itCode,quantity are part of the unique index . Then how to create the Model class ?

Answer (score 0):

The JPA model class can be created as below  with an ID as `PopularItemId` which is combination of the columns which are part of the unique index

```
@Table(name="popular_item")
@Entity
@NoArgConstructor
@AllArgCOnstructor
PopularItem{
@EmbeddedId
@AtrributeOverride(name="itemEntityId",column=@Column(name=""))
@AtrributeOverride(name="itemType",column=@Column(name="itemType"))
@AtrributeOverride(name="itCode",column=@Column(name="itCode"))
@AtrributeOverride(name="quantity",column=@Column(name="quantity"))
private PopularItemId popularItemId;
@Column(name="status")
private boolean status;
@Column(name="created_date")
private LocalDate createdDate;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgConstrucotor
@Embeddable
public class PopularItemId {
private String itemEntityId;
private String itemType;
private String itCode;
private Double quantity;
}
```